# Qual è il significato di "appostamento" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel libro autobiografico *Un grande avvenire dietro le spalle* di Vittorio Gassman ho letto:

> Durante la serata, E. mi svela candida i piccoli segreti del retropalco; tutte le ragazze si erano accorte del mio **appostamento**, e facevano scommesse su chi sarebbe stata la destinataria del bigliettino.

Ecco un brano precedente a questo che penso possa aiutare a capire il contesto:

> Sta lì sul palcoscenico, in uno stuolo di soubrettine in puntino, nella rivista *Paradiso per tutti* con Ugo Tognazzi. 
>         Io penso: «Che titolo azzeccato!» e giro fra le mani il bigliettino da visita già pronto per l'invito dopo lo spettacolo. È l'uso di quegli anni;  si va alla rivista come cani da punta, sulla segnalazione di qualche amico affezionato al genere.  «Va' al Valle. C'è la Masiero che è uno spettacolo, una triestina da svenire, una brunetta da capogiro, Flora Lillo. Poi c'è una polacca...» 
>         A chi lo mando, ora, il bigliettino? Quando E. fa il numero (immancabile) delle polinesiane, sciolgo ogni dubbio.

Non capisco molto bene il senso di "appostamento" nel primo brano. Nel [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/appostamento/) ho visto che significa "l'appostarsi" o il "luogo dove ci si apposta" e, dalla voce "[appostare](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/appostare1/)", apprendo che tale verbo vuol dire "fare la posta a qualcuno". Ignoro però il significato di quest'ultima espressione: non appare nella voce "[posta](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/posta/)" di questo dizionario. Nel Sabatini Coletti ho trovato che "[fare la posta a qualcuno](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/P/posta.shtml)" significa "attenderlo al varco", ma anche questa espressione mi è sconosciuta. Alla voce "[varco](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/V/varco.shtml)" ho visto che può significare "stare in agguato per coglierlo di sorpresa". Tuttavia, continuo a non capire del tutto bene il senso di "appostamento" nel brano sopra citato: che Gassman volesse cogliere qualche ragazza di sorpresa sembra contradirsi con l'affermazione che "tutte le ragazze si erano accorte". Per questa ragione vi chiedo: sapreste spiegarmi cosa significa "appostamento" nel primo brano che ho riportato?

Comment: Appostamento non è solo legato all'agguato vero e proprio, è anche un posto da dove poter osservare o spiare (per esempio una vedetta può essere "appostata" da qualche parte). Forse qui si limita all'idea di trovare un angolo da cui osservare senza mettersi troppo in vista (tentativo non molto riuscito).

Comment: @Charo, "disconoscere" significa "rinnegare" qualcuno o qualcosa. Ha quindi un significato specifico e non è usato in italiano come forma negativa di "conoscere", che in questo caso puoi dire o con "non conoscere" o con "ignorare".

Comment: Grazie mille, @Benedetta! Ho fatto la correzione.

Answer (score 2):

Appostamento viene utilizzato spesso quando le forze di polizia devono controllare un'uscita attendendo qualcuno (possibilmente per arrestarlo).
In questo contesto ha un significato ovviamente più leggero: significa che la persona sta ad aspettare qualcuno/a che deve passare/uscire da un luogo circoscritto. In questo caso per poi cercare una qualche interazione: consegnare un biglietto, evidentemente dato che tale azione era vistosa, le altre ragazze si erano accorte di tale comportamento, pertanto tale comportamento non era equivocabile.